# "EEEE, MMMM d, yyyy 'at' HH:mm"

Tags: java, simpledateformat

I am trying to convert from string to date. An example is :
 Wednesday, September 4, 2013 at 5:07pm

I first convert it to:
Wednesday, September 4, 2013 at 5:07 PM

And use the following code:

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE, MMMM d, yyyy 'at' hh:mm a");
```

But I always get the Unparseable date Exception.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Should there be a space before the final `a`?

Comment: it has a space before the a

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following works for me:

```
String str = "Wednesday, September 4, 2013 at 5:07 PM";
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE, MMMM d, yyyy 'at' hh:mm a", Locale.US);
```

But if I remove the `Locale`, then I get a `ParseException`. Your computer `Locale` corresponds probably not to a english speaking locale.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work fine:

```
SimpleDateFormat in = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE, MMMM d, yyyy 'at' hh:mma");
Date date = in.parse("Wednesday, September 4, 2013 at 5:07pm");
SimpleDateFormat out = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE, MMMM d, yyyy 'at' hh:mm a");
String result = out.format(date);
System.out.println(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use '**dd**' instead of '**d**'

So, instead of:

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE, MMMM d, yyyy 'at' hh:mm a");
```

Use:

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE, MMMM dd, yyyy 'at' hh:mm a");
```